# Running the redux saga i get 'Promise {<resolved>: undefined}'

Tags: redux-saga

I'm new to redux-saga and i get this 'Promise {: undefined}**proto**: Promise[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"[[PromiseValue]]: undefined' I just want a simple example to get running first thanks

Tried searching but have not found anything useful

```
function* fetcFunction() {
  try {
    const request = yield 
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1`)   

    yield put(test(request));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

function* Watcher() {
  yield takeLatest(FETCH_JSON, fetcFunction);
}

export default Watcher;
```

I expect to get a data.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `call` for api requests:

```js
const request = yield call(axios.get, 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
```